# Measuring values at nodes of two independent but now connected trees

Tags: trees

I am not sure if this the right forum for this question and I hope I am providing enough details on what I want to accomplish.

I have an application that has multiple trees -
Tree 1 - is categories/ attributes/ attribute values
There is a weight on each category, a score on attribute and a modified score on attribute value(s)
Tree 2 - is a set of Q & A (can have child questions) that is tied to attribute value. Think of this as additional details collected on the attribute value and it modifies the score on the attribute value.

I would like keep these separate so that I don't have to setup the Q&A sets over and over again. The same Q&A can be associated with multiple attribute values

Are there specific ways to setup the values on Q&A so that the way it modifies the score on the attribute value is consistent?

Thanks

Comment: It may just be me, but I did not understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Perhaps you may want to provide an example of these trees that you have mentioned. Also, the "decision theory" tag may not be appropriate here. Even though you are trying to decide on a structure, "decision theory" is a separate technical area that seems nothing to do with this question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_theory

Comment: Also keep in mind that if this a question about setting up a database of some sort, or it is about programming, other websites might be more appropriate and of more help.